# Iterar varias listas con enumerate en Python

Tags: python, lista, pandas

tengo problemas para iterar sobre varias listas, os comento, estoy creando un portfolio con optimización sobre carteras de criptomonedas, basándome en en una optimización de valores de bolsa, [aquí](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/portfolio-optimization-using-mpt-in-python/). Utiliza pandas para los dataframe, supongo que se podría hacer perfectamente con series en pandas pero en cualquier caso el ejemplo utiliza listas, convierte los dataframe en list y cuando intento iterar sobre estas listas me devuelve  "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" no puede iterar sobre ese tipo, he intentado crear lista de columnas y valores por separado, he intentado enumerar con zip y he lanza error de se espera 2 arreglo pero solo se proporciona uno, el caso es que las varias formas que he intentado me dan diferentes errores que no consigo solucionar, muestro el código y la salida, a ver si me podéis orientar, gracias de antemano.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  Importamos datos
ADA  = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\ADABUSD-1d.csv')
BNB  = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\BNBBUSD-1d.csv')
BTC  = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\BTCBUSD-1d.csv')
ETH = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\ETHBUSD-1d.csv')
XMR  = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\XMRBUSD-1d.csv')
LTC = pd.read_csv('F:\Inteligencia Artificial\Portfolio_LSTM\datasets\LTCBUSD-1d.csv')

#  Convert the date column to DateTime objects
ADA['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ADA['timestamp'])
BNB['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(BNB['timestamp'])
LTC['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(LTC['timestamp'])
BTC['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(BTC['timestamp'])
ETH['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(ETH['timestamp'])
XMR['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(XMR['timestamp'])


#  Make the dates the frame's index
ADA.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
BNB.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
BTC.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
ETH.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
XMR.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
LTC.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)


#  Resymbol the Close columns.  This is convenient when we build our new frames as the column symbols have to be unique
ADA = ADA.rename(columns = {'close': 'ADA'})
BNB = BNB.rename(columns = {'close': 'BNB'})
BTC = BTC.rename(columns = {'close': 'BTC'})
ETH = ETH.rename(columns = {'close': 'ETH'})
XMR = XMR.rename(columns = {'close': 'XMR'})
LTC = LTC.rename(columns = {'close': 'LTC'})


#  Select our date range
date_range = pd.date_range('2018-03-18', '2021-05-22')
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(index = date_range)

                
# Build our new data frame
portfolio = portfolio.join(ADA['ADA'], how = 'inner')
portfolio = portfolio.join(BNB['BNB'], how = 'inner')
portfolio = portfolio.join(BTC['BTC'], how = 'inner')
portfolio = portfolio.join(ETH['ETH'], how = 'inner')
portfolio = portfolio.join(XMR['XMR'], how = 'inner')
portfolio = portfolio.join(LTC['LTC'], how = 'inner')

### Comprobacion 
print(" Mostrando porfolio combinado")
#portfolio.to_csv ('portfolio.csv', index = None)
print(portfolio)
print(portfolio.dtypes)
print(portfolio.columns)


#  Normalize the price data
portfolio = portfolio / portfolio.iloc[0]

return_portfolio = portfolio.pct_change()
return_portfolio.head()

weight_portfolio = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
portfolio_return = return_portfolio.dot(weight_portfolio)
portfolio_return.head()

variance_matrix = return_portfolio.cov()*365 # (252 dias habiles si fuesen acciones)

# Computing portfolio variance
portfolio_variance = np.transpose(weight_portfolio)@variance_matrix@weight_portfolio

#Computing portfolio volatility (Risk)
portfolio_volatility = np.sqrt(portfolio_variance)

print("Portfolio Varianza:", portfolio_variance)
print("Portfolio Volatilidad:", portfolio_volatility)

# Intialize an empty list for sotring the portfolio returns
port_returns = []
# Initialize an empty list for stroing the portfolio volatility
port_volatility = []
# Initialize an enmpty list for sotring the portfolio weight
port_weights = []

num_assests = len(portfolio.columns)
num_portfolios = 100

# Computing the individual asset return
individual_rets = portfolio.resample('Y').last().pct_change().mean()

for port in range(num_portfolios):
    # Ramdomly generate weigh combination
    weights = np.random.random()
    port_weights.append(weights)
    # Return are the dot product of indivuadual expect return of asset and its weight
    returns = np.dot(weights, individual_rets)
    port_returns.append(returns)

    # Computing Portfolio Variance
    var = variance_matrix.mul(weights, axis=0).mul(weights, axis=1).sum().sum()
    # Daily standard deviation: volatility is square root of variance
    sd = np.sqrt(var)
    # Annualizing the standard deviation will give us the volatility
    ann_sd = sd*np.sqrt(365) #250 habiles
    port_volatility.append(ann_sd)


# Creating dictionary of returns and volatility
data = {'Returns':port_returns, 'Volatility':port_volatility}

for counter, symbol in enumerate (portfolio.columns.tolist()):
         data[symbol+'weight'] = [w[counter] for w in port_weights]


# Converting the dictionary to dataframe
portfolios_V1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
portfolios_V1.head()
print(portfolios_V1)

# Plot efficient frontier
#portfolios_V1.plot.scatter(x='Volatility', y='Returns', marker='o', color='y',
#                        s=15, alpha=0.5, grid=True, figsize=[8,8])
#plt.ylabel("Expected Returns")

# Min Volatility
# idxmin() gives us the minimum value in the column that has been specified
min_vol_port = portfolios_V1.iloc[portfolios_V1['Volatility'].idxmin()]
print(min_vol_port)

#Finding the optimal portfolio: Highest SHARPE RATIO
rf = 0.01
optimal_risky_port = portfolios_V1.iloc[((portfolios_V1['Returns']-rf)/portfolios_V1['Volatility']).
                                        idxmax()]
print(optimal_risky_port)


# Plotting optimal portfolio and minimum volatility
plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
plt.scatter(portfolios_V1['Volatility'], portfolios_V1['Returns'], maker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3, color='green')
plt.scatter(min_vol_port[1], min_vol_port[0], color='y', maker='*', s=500)
plt.scatter(optimal_risky_port[1], optimal_risky_port[0], color='b', maker='*', s=500)
plt.xlabel("Risk (Volatility)")
plt.ylabel("Excepted Returns")
```

y esta es la salida

```
Mostrando porfolio combinado
                ADA       BNB       BTC      ETH     XMR     LTC
2020-02-27  0.04973   19.1268   8815.88   227.60   70.33   61.61
2020-02-28  0.04901   19.0454   8706.48   227.15   69.13   59.98
2020-02-29  0.04712   19.2689   8524.53   217.48   65.97   58.03
2020-03-01  0.04556   18.9225   8525.69   217.40   64.73   57.74
2020-03-02  0.04895   19.9119   8916.01   232.04   68.42   61.20
...             ...       ...       ...      ...     ...     ...
2021-05-18  2.00360  508.2100  42870.07  3377.49  340.92  294.05
2021-05-19  1.47000  335.4700  36736.94  2443.89  197.93  186.67
2021-05-20  1.80420  391.8900  40647.10  2774.43  281.57  211.18
2021-05-21  1.55130  326.7600  37330.71  2433.36  256.48  180.24
2021-05-22  1.46530  300.0800  37482.50  2297.14  230.90  169.45

[451 rows x 6 columns]
ADA    float64
BNB    float64
BTC    float64
ETH    float64
XMR    float64
LTC    float64
dtype: object
Index(['ADA', 'BNB', 'BTC', 'ETH', 'XMR', 'LTC'], dtype='object')
Portfolio Varianza: 0.34744830030009155
Portfolio Volatilidad: 0.5894474533833288
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Inteligencia Artificial/Portfolio_LSTM/portfolio_test.py", line 119, in <module>
    data[symbol+'weight'] = [w[counter] for w in port_weights]
  File "f:/Inteligencia Artificial/Portfolio_LSTM/portfolio_test.py", line 119, in <listcomp>
    data[symbol+'weight'] = [w[counter] for w in port_weights]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
PS F:\Inteligencia Artificial>
```

Comment: No me he leido todo tu código (demasiado largo y complejo!) pero voy a intentar saltarme pasos e ir al posible problema. Tienes `[w[counter] for w in port_weights]`, pero si `port_weights` es ya una lista, entonces `w` será cada uno de sus elementos, por lo que sobra lo de `[counter]`. Aunque realmente no entiendo qué intentas con esa línea.

Comment: Esa linea lo que hace, es que a cada tipo de moneda se le asigna los pesos aleatorios de port_weights, van encorchado [x,x,x,x,x,x] 6 monedas 6 pesos que su suma es 1, y para eso calcula la volatilidad y la varianza,  si elimino el counter arroja TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype```

Comment: Al no entender por completo el resto de estructuras de datos que estás usando, no sé si lo siguiente funcionaría o no, pero ¿quizás lo que intentas sería esto?: `data[symbol+'weight'] = port_weights[counter]`? En ese caso el bucle entero podría reducirse a `data.update({symbol+'weight': weight for symbol, weight in zip(portfolio.columns, port_weights)})`. Si esto te funciona puedo convertirlo en una respuesta en la que lo explique mejor, si te interesa.